# Spring security - Disable CSRF and Authentication for specific URL (Java Conf)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I know this question is old but it is not working in my case.
I have a webapp using spring security authentication and CSRF enabled.

Now I want to expose couple of URL to expose to other application without authentication.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/book").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/check").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            //.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();

}
```

I have other urls with "/rest/" which are secure. I tried csrfMatcher and with that I am able to expose "/rest/book" but then other urls are giving unexpected behavior.

Unexpected behavior like, my default login page is /login when no authentication but it stopped.

Comment: Calling /rest/book will redirect to the login page with your current setup?

Comment: It should redirect to login page. Now I set it to permitAll so it should not redirect over there. And I have csrf enabled for this app. "/rest/book" is a post method so it would need csrf token. I also want to disable csrf for particular url.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @NatFar, No it is not solved yet